# Show that a group of order 66 has a normal subgroup of order 33.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This question is somewhat similar to: [A group of order $66$ has an element of order $33$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114278/a-group-of-order-66-has-an-element-of-order-33).

However, I do not understand how I would show that the subgroup of order 33 is normal. So far I have that there is a unique Sylow 11-subgroup, but I don't know how to continue.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Every subgroup of index $2$ is normal - see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790373/any-group-of-index-2-is-normal?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Related; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal

Comment: I would say that your question is fully covered by [this more general result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/225987/11619). I won't vote to close right away, because there is scope for disagreement. I have the dupehammer on [tag:group-theory], so my vote would be immediately binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ be the Sylow $11$-subgroup you've shown exists. Since you've shown $P$ is unique, we have that $P$ is normal. Now if we let $Q$ be a Sylow $3$-subgroup, then $PQ=QP$ by normality of $P$, and thus $PQ$ is a subgroup of $G$. But $PQ$ has order $33$ (hence index $2$) so $PQ$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

We know by the linked answer that there exists an element of order $33$. Let this element be $x$. Hence, $\langle x\rangle$ has order $33$. We [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84632/subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal?noredirect=1&lq=1) that all subgroups with index 2 in a group are normal.